# Covariance of stochastic integral

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, covariance

I have a big problem with such a task:

> Calculate $\text{Cov} \, (X_t,X_r)$ where $X_t=\int_0^ts^3W_s \, dW_s$, $t \ge 0$.

I've tried to do this in this way: setting up $t \le r$
$$\text{Cov} \, (X_t,X_r)=\text{Cov} \,  \left(\int_0^ts^3W_s \, dW_s,\int_0^rs^3W_s \, dW_s \right)=\int_0^t s^6 W^2_s \, ds$$
And I've stacked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> $\text{Cov} \, (X_t,X_r)=\text{Cov} \, (\int_0^ts^3W_sdW_s,\int_0^rs^3W_sdW_s)=\int_0^t s^6 W^2_s ds$

This identity does not hold true. Note that the left-hand side is a fixed real number whereas the right-hand side is a random variable.

If you apply Itô's isometry correctly, you find

$$\text{cov} \, (X_t,X_r) = \color{red}{\mathbb{E} \bigg( }\int_0^t s^6 W_s^2 \, ds \color{red}{\bigg)}.$$

Applying Tonelli's theorem yields

$$\text{cov} \, (X_t,X_r) = \int_0^t s^6 \mathbb{E}(W_s^2) \, ds.$$

Now, since $W_s \sim N(0,s)$, we have $\mathbb{E}(W_s^2) = s$, and therefore the integral can be easily calculated.

Comment: Whenever I see Ito's Symmetry online, the limits of integration are the same. Why can we change the limits of integration here on $X(r)$ to match the limits on $X(t)$?

Comment: @alpast It holds that $$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^T f(s) \, dW_s \cdot \int_0^T g(s) \, dW_s \right) = \mathbb{E} \int_0^T f(s) g(s) \, ds;$$ this follows from the polarization identity and Itô's formula.

Comment: But here we have this $$\text{Cov} \,  \left(\int_0^ts^3W_s \, dW_s,\int_0^rs^3W_s \, dW_s \right)$$ and in the identity you posted the limits of integration match. But since $t<r$ can we extend $s^3$ from $[0,r]$ to $[0,t]$ by making it $0$ on $[r,t]$ then apply Ito's Symmetry and this would then yield your above answer?

Comment: @alpast yes, exactly.

Comment: If the integration limits are $[0,s]$ and $[s,t]$, then it is correct that the covariance of these two stochastic processes over non-overlapping intervals is zero?

Comment: @BrownianBread Yes, that's correct.